# "Microsoft Word has encountered a [redacted] and needs to close."

Tags: microsoft-word, debug

Every time I try to open Word (v 15.11.2), it does not open, an instead gives a popup with the message "Microsoft Word has encountered a problem and needs to close."  If I select to restart Word, the popup just appears again.  I have tried restarting the computer(MacBook Pro (Sierra 10.12)), but the problem persists.

Comment: What version of Office are you using.  Have you tried to repair the installation?  Edit your question instead of replying with a comment

Comment: Did you try [Repair an Office application](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Repair-an-Office-application-7821d4b6-7c1d-4205-aa0e-a6b40c5bb88b)?

Comment: @DavidPostill The instructions there are only for windows.

Comment: [Word for Mac error: "Microsoft Word has encountered a problem and needs to close"](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2693802/word-for-mac-error-microsoft-word-has-encountered-a-problem-and-needs)

Comment: @DavidPostill There is no library in the home menu on my mac.

Comment: "If you have OS X 10.7 (Lion) or above, click Go, hold down the OPTION key and choose Library."

Comment: I can't click on library while pressing the option key because I can't see library at all.

Comment: @DavidPostill I found the library, but I am missing both the file in preferences and the microsoft folder.

Comment: So try reinstalling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your version of Mac Office is almost 3-years out of date. If you are running a Retail (perpetual) version of Mac Office 2016, your version number should 16.16.3.

It makes no sense to try and diagnose what the issue is unless you bring your Office software up to current patch levels.